# Describe up to isomorphism all 2d associative algebras with 1 and without 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question:

> Describe up to isomorphism all 2d associative algebras over Ring with 1 and without 1

That's all info, that I found about this question:

> Every two-dimensional associative algebra is either equivalent or
>   isomorphic to one of the eight algebras.

But I don't know how it can be proved. 
There was [something similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24601/classsifying-1-and-2-dimensional-algebras-up-to-isomorphism) to my problem, but with Lie-group theory which I don't understand.

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102998/classification-of-two-dimensional-algebras-without-unit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion "2d" makes sense for algebras over a *field* (namely the dimension of its underlying $K$-vecor space), but is not "defined" over rings. I suppose you mean $R$ perhaps as $\mathbb{R}$, the field of real numbers.
Goze and Remm have classified all $2$-dimensional algebras over an arbitrary field $K$, see [here](http://www.fsr.ac.ma/GNPHE/ajmpVolume10N1-2011/ajmp1109.pdf). It is easy to pick out the associative ones form their list. Independently, many people already did this classification, see for example  the recent colourful slides [here](https://pgssblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/tp6-pgss_finalpresentation.pdf). The idea is easy. Take as basis $(e_1,e_2)$ and write
all basis products $e_i.e_j$ in this basis, with coefficients $a_{ij}$. Then determine the conditions for associativity and compute isomorphisms.